# Transformar 2 Select Simples em 1

Tags: php, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela `PLAYLIST` onde tenho as colunas `VIDEO` e `STATUS`:

```
VIDEO | STATUS
```

A coluna `status` varia entre `1` e `0` sendo `1` para videos novos e `0` para vídeos que já foram assistidos.

Atualmente estou realizando dois `select`:

```
SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE status='1';
if result > 0  { 
   echo ok
} else {
 SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE status='0'
}
```

Da pra fazer essa consulta utilizando somente em 1 `SELECT`? de preferencia sem utilizar php?

Meu objetivo é priorizar os vídeos que não foram vistos.

Comment: Só tirar o `where` não resolve? tem algum problema?

Comment: Mas ele quer o resultado restante, onde o status é 0. Não é ?

Comment: e bem parecido com o if do php so que queria como sql ,

Comment: Você quer pegar os dados da tabela playlist que o status for 1 e se caso o resultado for vazio (nenhuma linha) pegar todos que o status for 0?

Comment: acredito que `status` só pode ter os valores `0` e `1`; sendo assim, você realmente não precisaria do `where`, como @rray falou.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam sim exatamente isso

Comment: o usuario quando posta o video ele ja vai com o status=1 ,  ao ser assistido o video da update no status e marca o video como 0 = ja foi exibido , e o select é para que se todos os video ja tiverem sido exibidos ele vai rodar os que tem status=0

Comment: Não sei é a finalidade do código mas uma opção é `count()` com `group by` o retorno tem a coluna `status` e quantas vezes (`total`) ele apareceu.

Comment: Por que não usar só a última consulta então? `SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE status='0'`

Comment: @rLinhares rray  finalidade no comentario de cima, basicamente quero priorizar os novos videos que foi inserido

Comment: Se você quer apenas priorizar pode usar `ORDER BY status DESC`, assim aqueles com status 1 vão vir primeiro, mas se não puder aparecer aqueles com status 0 se houver algum com status 1, da uma olhada na minha resposta, acredito que é o que procura

Comment: reamente matou a charada pelo status vai dar certinho em 1 so consulta, agora so me fala como faco pra ordenar pelo ID e STATUS ao mesmo tempo ORDER BY ID.STATUS DESC?

Comment: Se usar `ORDER BY status DESC` ele vai ordenar pelo status e depois pelo id, por que no banco a ordem natural é pelo id, mas se quiser pode usar `ORDER BY status DESC, id`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam posta la como resposta para eu marcar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que isso resolva:

```
SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM playlist WHERE status = 1) = 0 
    THEN status = 0
    ELSE status = 1
END
```

Se a contagem de `playlist` com `status = 1` for 0 faz uma busca com `status = 0` senão, faz uma busca com `status = 1`

Mas se você quer apenas priorizar pode usar `ORDER BY status DESC`, assim aqueles com status 1 vão vir primeiro

Comment: entendi é bem isso mesmo ja eliminou o php, porem continua 2 SELECT.

Comment: De qualquer forma será necessário um select para saber se existe ou não dados com `status = 1`, e outro que vai retornar o que precisa

Comment: o seu comentario na pergunta matou a charada